# How do I tell the difference between 'dd' and 'tt' in words?

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling

I have a spelling bee today and I would like some tips on how to differentiate 'tt' and 'dd' in words.  Words like bottle and prattle have a 'tt', but most people pronounce it like a 'dd', like in waddle or ruddle.  Is there a way to tell by pronunciation alone which double letter it is?  Thanks! :)

Comment: If you are living in America, I'm not surprised to hear you say that. Come to Britain and you will hear them pronounced with 'tt'.

Comment: ...Yes, 'wattle' might be a bit of a problem in an American spelling competition.

Comment: This makes me all the happier with my ladder/latter joke. :)

Comment: Those are pronounced very nearly the same in most cases.  The alert, well-trained ear might hear the difference, but it depends a lot on the speaker and the context.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Except that an alert competitor would ask for the word to be defined.

Comment: Even if *mettle* and *meddle* were sufficiently different in pronunciation, you'd still need to distinguish them from *metal* and *medal*. By the same token, there's no such word as *praddle* or *fittle*, but you'd only know that through experience. So unfortunately, there are no tricks; you just have to memorize them. And that is why spelling bees are entertaining.

Comment: And it's certainly impossible to properly spell homophones without context. Heck, even with context, "to, too, and two", "their and they're", "threw and through", etc., are misspelled or misused -- by native speakers, no less.

Comment: @WS2  if you come to Britain you'll hear it pronounced with a 't':D You don't hear anything pronounced with a 'tt' in English ;) [Technically I should have said "you'll hear it pronounced with a /t/"!]

Comment: The point of spelling bees is to know the spelling of words.  In the case of ambiguity the provided definition will disambiguate.

Comment: @WS2 What is the purpose of your comment? Most people understand that there are differences between American and British English. It's not necessary to point them out all the time.

Comment: @only_pro The OP was querying why they were not pronounced "tt". My comment merely points out that in Britain they are. What's so wrong with that?

Comment: @WS2 OP is obviously not in Britain...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no possible way to infer the guaranteed-correct spelling of an unknown word by merely hearing its pronunciation coming from one or another speaker.  That is not how English works.

Comment: I will vote for that!